# Brightness and volume keys don't work when logged out

Tags: 16.04, login-screen, function-keys

The `flight mode` key and `enable/disable touch-pad` keys work on the other hand. The `lock screen` key  for some reason makes a character appear in the password entry box.

Also, the volume settings appear to be separate for when I am logged in and for when I am logged out.

I use Lenovo ideapad 510-15IKB.

Comment: Could you explain why this is a problem? You're logged out, so why would you need thee buttons to work? Also, in order to be able to fix this we would need to know what hardware you are using. I assume this is a laptop, but what laptop? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: For example I might accidentally move the mouse, then the screen turns on and I want to decrease the brightness to save power and I don't want to log in and log out again so that it dims itself. Conversely, I might want to increase the brightness because I decreased it to 0 earlier. I might want to turn off the computer but I want to change the sound of the drums that play when I turn it on again. I might want to turn on my computer in the library and I want to immediately hit mute so that the sound of the drums causes as little disruption as possible. The last scenario happened to me.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks. Turning off those sounds is the first thing I do on any new computer so I had forgotten about them!